# Counting Years Not Explicitly Listed

Tags: db2

Here is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_b (
  name VARCHAR(255),
  date_2 DATE,
  date_3 DATE,
  var CHAR(1)
);


INSERT INTO table_b (name, date_2, date_3, var) VALUES
('john', '2001-01-01', '2015-01-01', 'b'),
('sara', '2000-01-01', '2015-01-01', 'c'),
('sara', '2015-01-02', '2022-01-01', 'a'),
('tim', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 'a'),
('john', '1998-01-01', '1999-01-01', 'd');

#table_b



name     date_2     date_3 var
 john 2001-01-01 2015-01-01   b
 sara 2000-01-01 2015-01-01   c
 sara 2015-01-02 2022-01-01   a
  tim 2020-01-01 2021-01-01   a
 john 1998-01-01 1999-01-01   d
```

Between the overall min and max year, I want to find out: at each year, how many people had records in this table?

Here is the approach I thought of:

```
with years as (
select 1998 as year
union all 
select 1999
union all
##etc etc)

counts as 
(select y.year
count(distinct t.name) as count
from table_b t
join years y
on t.date_2 <= date(y.year || '-12-31') and t.date_3  >= date(y.year || '-01-01')
group by y.year)
select * from counts;
```

Is there an easier way to do this without having to manually list all years?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a year list from the existing date fields by using a recursive CTE. You can take the minimum date (from `date_2`) and `UNION ALL` inside of a CTE with a stop condition of the maximum year (from `date_3`).

This example assumes that `date_2` is always less than the corresponding `date_3`.

```sql
WITH YEARS_LIST (YR, YR_STOP) AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(MIN(DATE_2)) AS YR,
        YEAR(MAX(DATE_3)) AS YR_STOP
    FROM TABLE_B

    UNION ALL

    -- Generate a row for each year until we get to the max year
    SELECT
        YR + 1 AS YR,
        YR_STOP
    FROM YEARS_LIST
    WHERE YR < YR_STOP
),

COUNTS AS (
    SELECT
        Y.YR,
        COUNT(DISTINCT T.NAME) AS REC_COUNT
    FROM TABLE_B AS T
    INNER JOIN YEARS_LIST AS Y
        ON
            T.DATE_2 <= DATE(Y.YR || '-12-31')
            AND T.DATE_3 >= DATE(Y.YR || '-01-01')
    GROUP BY Y.YR
)

SELECT *
FROM COUNTS;
```

*Note: I've modified some of the column names from your example to avoid using some keyword (e.g. YEAR, COUNT).*

The first iteration of the CTE will make a row like this:

| YR | YR_STOP |
| --- | --- |
| 1998 | 2022 |

The second select statement in the CTE will loop, generating a row with `YR` incremented by 1, until `YR` is equal to or greater than the `YR_STOP`.

The resulting CTE will resemble this:

| YR | YR_STOP |
| --- | --- |
| 1998 | 2022 |
| 1999 | 2022 |
| 2000 | 2022 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021 | 2022 |
| 2022 | 2022 |